# forward iterators, how to return const value

Tags: c++, class, struct, iterator, constants

I have made a dynamic array class, each element in the array is defined via struct made like this

```
template <typename T>
struct element{
    int i;
    int j;
    T val;
};
```

I have defined forward iterator and const iterator for my class, the iterator needs to return to return `i, j, val` but only val can be modifiable, `i` and `j` can not be modified.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending @Bathsheba's answer, your iterators could return this struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct element_ref {
    const int& i;
    const int& j;
    T& val;

    element_ref(element& e) : i(e.i), j(e.j), val(e.val) {}
};
```

Its constructor takes the actual element and stores references to its fields. only the `val` reference is modifiable.

Comment: Yeah, this is getting hotter.

Answer (score 2):

In some ways it can be a pain in the backside since you have to rewrite the constructors and assignment operators, but you *could* write

```
template <typename T>
struct element{
    int i;
    int j;
    T val;
    const int& _i;
    const int& _j;
};
```

and bind `_i`, and `_j` to `i` and `j` on construction. Your forward iterator returns those references, rather than `i` and `j` directly.

If someone can think of a better way then please downvote this.

Comment: But in the iterator i have a member data like: element<T> *ptr, i never access i and j directly. i would post the iterator but is 70 lines, is it fine?